# Raw mouse input on mobile

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use a physical mouse connected to a mobile device and track its events in my Flutter application to control the PC as if the mouse were connected to it.

How to ensure continuous and unlimited mouse movement? I have an application installed that can do just that, but it's not open source.

I've tried `Listener` and `MouseRegion`, but the mouse just rests against the borders of the screen.

Comment: It is unclear how you are connecting the PC to your Android app. Be aware that Flutter is a UI framework and depends upon the native Java/Kotlin/C code to do certain things on device. The key terms to search on is 'human interface device' or 'HID'.  See: [Reading raw mouse data on android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13280402/295004)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I connect my mobile device to a PC via Bluetooth. I've already tried what you suggested, but for some reason it doesn't work, as if it doesn't see the connected mouse at all. I'll try something else soon, but for now I'm confused by the current situation.

Comment: Okay, it was a cheap mouse. I connected another one, and now everything is working...